# Setting a preferred deployment location in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azureportal

When deploying resource in Azure, the default location is always `Central US`.
[image]

Is there any way to configure a *preferred location*? I cannot find any documentation about this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know which geography meets my needs, but this location is not selected by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported as of now. It could be due to few reasons a company might prefer deployments across various regions and different subscriptions.

However if you badly need this upvote this [`uservoice`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/40472674-allow-setting-a-default-region)

Answer (score 0):

When deploying the resource in the portal, it will not choose the preferred location for you automatically. But you could choose it manually by yourself, generally, we consider it from compliance to resiliency features.

To find the Azure geography that meets your needs, you could follow this link.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/geographies/